# Using Google Compute VMs to run windows .exes from local machine

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm a complete n00b to cloud computing so just need a little guidance on what I can actually do with it.

I want to be able to run a plethora of 32bit windows modelling applications in parallel - ideally over 100 instances at once. Each model run will create ~5 gig worth of files, which will be processed and deleted internally - this will reduce file size transfers over the server. Each model run requires ~2gig of ram to run effectively. The model runs are fortran based .exes and create simple text file outputs.

My question is - **is this achievable on google cloud compute and can someone point to a tutorial which is not web server oriented?**

I'd like the fire the model runs off from the commandline on my local machine. I've previously been using PSEXEC to run my models across a local network using a .bat file, so it would be amazing if I could just jig my existing code and fire off 200 model runs off into the cloud. **Is this possible with gcutil?**

**Do I just need to set up a buttload of virtual machines - or do I need to set up APIs also? I assume I'll have to use Windows2008server?**

Sorry for the vague questions. Its just all new to me and might save me 6 hours trawling through compute forums.

Many thanks

Comment: No personal experience but the docs are here -- https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/operating-systems/windows

Comment: Why not use Amazon who have supported Windows VMs from the beginning?

Comment: Ah yes, thanks - think I'll try the amazon route. I just heard google was a little faster and cheaper, but doesn't look like its ideal for me.

Answer (score 0):

gcutil has been deprecated and substituted by gcloud. gcloud sdk (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/) will let you manage your resources in your Google project from the command line interface. It can be installed in Linux, Mac or Windows machines.  gcloud was not conceived to run processes in remotes machines as PSEXEC does. Some of the functionality of gcloud includes but is not limited to:

- Create and delete GCE instances and persistent disks.
- Attach or detach a disk to a GCE instance.
- Create images and snapshots from a disk.
- Create firewall rules and routes in your network.
- Manage the authentication and credentials in your project.

Once your instances are created, you should be able to use PSEXEC to execute processes in your windows cloud instances. You have to setup your firewall rules to allow this communication (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking). Be aware that windows cloud OS images are still on Beta  (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/operating-systems/windows). Access to this images might require pre-approval and will lead to additional charges 
(https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/operating-systems/).

In regards to the memory capacity you have a variety of machines types (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types).